# Is rails ujs (unobtrusive javascript) mainly used for ajax?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, unobtrusive-javascript

I am fairly new to the rails world.  I love the rails ujs concept as it makes life easy and less messy for deletes, links and ajax forms.

I am wondering if there is a proper way of dealing with other javascript functions.  right now I have these stuffed under document.ready in custom.js in the assets folder. I get this file loaded using sprockets.

But this does not (at least to my knowledge) allow the use of <%= escape_javascript .... %> types of interlacing with server-side objects.  Is that correct?  Is there a way to have .js.erb files that are not linked to particular actions?  I have looked at one approach that essentially involves use of virtual properties on the model and hidden text fields in html.  But I am keeping an open mind on how to approach this.

How do you handle javascript code that does not relate directly with the action methods but requires information from the server-side? Is there a better way compare to stuffing it into custom.js and using hidden variables to pass server-side values?

Thanks,
Tabrez

Comment: *"I want to leave this as an open-ended question."*... Bad idea! [ask]

Comment: Fair point mac.  I am changing it to "I am keeping an open mind" because that's what my intention was.